# Inconsistent results querying temporary table in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-cursor

I am creating a temporary table `alarm_clusters` within a stored procedure. If I return results via `SELECT * FROM alarm_clusters` I get the expected results set:

```
id |alarm_timestamp     |alarm_rule_id |sensor_id |cluster_duration |time_delta |cluster_id |
---|--------------------|--------------|----------|-----------------|-----------|-----------|
1  |2018-01-01 00:00:00 |1             |1         |60               |0          |1          |
2  |2018-01-01 00:02:00 |1             |1         |60               |120        |2          |
3  |2018-01-01 00:02:20 |1             |1         |60               |20         |2          |
```

whereas if I return only a single column `SELECT alarm_timestamp FROM alarm_clusters;` I get the value of that column in the last row repeated:

```
alarm_timestamp     |
--------------------|
2018-01-01 00:02:20 |
2018-01-01 00:02:20 |
2018-01-01 00:02:20 |
```

I have created a [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4qApZRAMLnwoRrHaJaRt3k/2) with two versions of the stored proc.

What have I missed?

Comment: Not able to reproduce what you say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the same time stamp because you are using the declared variable in your select query inside the procedure **alarm_timestamp**

Check below line in your getAlarmTimestamps procedure.

```
SELECT alarm_timestamp FROM alarm_clusters;
```

Ideally you should use different name variable rather than same as table column variable to avoid such kind of small mistakes.

Variable **alarm_timestamp** has last value which you have set in your cursor, and this value display total times of your rows in alarm_clusters table

I hope this will solve your confusion